# Angular 6 style background image return null value not updated

Tags: angular

i've searching about how to use the [ngStyle] [style.backgroundImage] but when i'm implemented in my project the value return null

http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)

my code something like this

```
getMyStyles(img) {
    const myStyles = {
      'background-image': 'url(\'' + img + '\')'
    };
    return myStyles;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.pesertaService.getImage(this.idHasilSimulasi, this.idPaket)
      .then((response) => {
this.img = response.img;
})
}
```

and my html

```
<div [ngStyle]="getMyStyles(img)" [style.backgroundSize]="'cover'" [style.height.px]="300"> </div>
```

i also have tring this

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ img +')'"
```

what i'm supposed to do?

Comment: Have you tried to hard-code the URL into the assignment? Does this work? Maybe your url is wrong? 404 tells you that it's not an angular/syntax error but your browser can't load the ressource.

Comment: What the value of `img` is it binary or url ?

Comment: the assets path like assets/firstImage.jpg, the image actually show if i using the style="background-image:url('assets/firstImage.jpg')" but i want a dynamic image.. The getMyStyles function return the correct path also

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thought,

when your component renders, it calls ngOnInit() but due to asynchronous behavior of getImage it ends and getMyStyles() will be called from HTML at that point image might not have arrived and

```
this.img = response.img;
```

might not have been executed,

another case could be `response.img` is null by itself or not valid URL